# Copying files from failing hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, chkdsk

Unable to boot to windows 7, running rescue disk, using C: prompt. I can see the windows partition(C:) but not rest of drive (E:),no access or dir. CHKDSK E: says there are errors in "index $130 for file 111685". CHKDSK failed to continue. CHKDSK E:/r "unable to read the Usn journal $J data stream". I removed drive & hooked up as external drive still no access.

I know this drive is dying fast. I want to copy some files or the whole partition E:, but I cannot access it. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: If you cannot access it then you cannot copy the files.  What you have attempted is pretty much you should be doing.  There isn't a great deal of options, the filesystem has already started to remove files its detected has being unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image it.  e.g. Macrium Reflect is free(as in no cost) software that lets you make an image of a partition or I suppose of a disk.

I haven't tried this but you could try disk2vhd, and then load the vhd in a virtual machine.    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx

I once ran chkdsk /r while a drive was failing and it failed -while- running chkdsk - click of death. That was a once in a million bad luck.

But making an image would involve no writing. And from there you could run chkdsk.  I once heard also that is what hard drive repair places do, because any work on a hard drive could cause it to fail.   Perhaps if there's just some files to copy you could just copy those. But if more than that then image it.

Comment: I burned HIRENS Bootcd, selected Parted Magic. Ran TestDisk to verify partitions. Then imaged partition and copied to external usb harddrive, just in case. I then went to File Manager and was able to copy 80% of the files to the external drive. Tried several boot programs, only Hirens worked flawlessly. Will replace drive and clone a new Win 7 iso and system disk. Thanks for your help, Mark this problem..SOLVED!

Comment: @LINDA Been a while since I used Hirens. What program within Hirens did you use to image the partition?  There should be a tick by an answer you can click that says it answered it. So you could tick mine or post your own answer and accept that.

Comment: I used Image Creation in TestDisk, I have not restored the image yet since I was able to copy the files. Tried Partition Image but it couldn't see the file structure. PhotoRec was next choice. I was able to access the drive twice but it has since died. Oh, well.

Comment: PhotoRec & Clonezilla was next choice. I was able to access the drive twice but it has since died. Oh, well. Also tried BootMed, Ubuntu Rescue Remix, UNetbootin, SystemRescueCd.

Comment: @LINDA With a good program that works with images you should be able to extract individual files from an image without restoring the whole thing that works great as a test too.